# Internet Explorer 7 - Position Absolute - Dropdown Menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-position, internet-explorer-6

I am having a big trouble positioning my dropdown menu on below URL (Internet Explorer 7 problem only):

http://tinyurl.com/y7v2qj9

When hovering the menu, you will see that the drop down appears behind the image. This doesn´t happen in IE8 or Firefox, only in IE7. I think it must be related to a specific bug which i am unaware of, can´t find the solution.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Matias - You should accept the answer that helped you resolve each question by clicking the empty check-mark beside it...this makes your questions much more appealing to answer...the reverse drives people away, like the previous comment.

Comment: THanks Nick, I wasnt aware of that... I ´ll do it from now onwards.

Comment: Note that when an answer didn't actually answer/solve the question/problem, you don't need to accept it :) Just accept the one which *actually* did and/or is the most useful.

Answer (score 0):

Give the list items a `z-index` value which is higher than the image. E.g.:

```
ul.dropdown li {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried but that doesn´t work, the image is in a separate container and is not positioned aboluted.

Comment: You've a lot of unassigned rules at bottom of `main.css`. Remove them or at least add a `{}` for each rule.